# C++ std::cout and string printing in wrong order

Tags: c++, g++

I have a simple program running on Linux using g++ compiler:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
 fstream file;
 string s;
 file.open("sample/dates.dat", fstream::in);
 if(!file.good())
  return 0;
 getline(file, s);
 cout << s << "." << endl;
 return 0;

}
```

Compiled with: `g++ -o test test.cpp`. When I run this, the fullstop is printed BEFORE the string s, not after. Does anybody know why this is happening? And is it easy to fix?
Thanks.

Comment: What about the contents of `dates.dat`? Are you sure the character isn't at the beginning of the string or a carriage return at the end of the line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is a carriage return at the end of the string it will move the position of output to the beginning of the console line when printed.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "some line\r" << "." << std::endl;
    //                     ^^ carriage return
}
```

Comment: How do I know if there is a `'\r'` at the end of the line?

Comment: +1. If you're on *nix, use `dos2unix dates.dat` (after making a backup) to convert from `\r\n` lines to `\n` lines. If this works, fix your code to handle stray `\r`'s.

Comment: Do a hex dump of the file with `hexdump` or similar utility.

Comment: The carriage return will be value `0D` and a linefeed/newline will be `0A`

Comment: Thanks this helped! I did not know about the `'\r'` character.

Comment: @Toby As a rule of thumb, when you read a text  file from unkwnown origin (Windows, Unix and MacOS) you should somehow "normalize" the line delimiters. One way to do it is to first transform `\r\n` to `\n` (Windows to Unix format) then transform the remaining `\r` to `\n` (MacOS to Unix format). Then you can process all your lines using only `\n` as a line delimiter. This may not be the most efficient method but it's the easiest one.